# Oracle SQL group by and select first_value

Tags: sql, oracle

I need to do a group by on column code_train and code_emp and select the average of nb_hrs.
and get the first value of column description in the group

```
code_train       code_emp   nb_hrs   description
abc              001        3        analytic
abc              002        5        analytic
def              007        6        finance
def              005        7        finance
```

I tried this

```
select code_train, code_emp, avg(nb_hrs) as nb, First_value(description)
from table
group by code_train, code_emp
```

the problem is asking me to add description in the group by. which i do not want.

Comment: Do you mean simply `min(description)`? If not, what do you mean by "first value" of column in the group? How are the rows in each group "ordered"?

Answer (score 2):

The function you want looks like this in Oracle:

```
select code_train, code_emp, avg(nb_hrs) as nb,
       max(description) keep (dense_rank first order by code_emp) as first_description
from table
group by code_train, code_emp
```

Comment: Ordering in `first/last` by a column that is also in `group by` is a beginner mistake. `code_emp` is constant in each group. Congrats on the multiple up-votes!